# How to get and count the row of table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

- Initially I have a data sheet like this

[image]

- What I want is that after using the SQL the SQL will produce a table like this

[image]

- I have just learned SQL, have tried count () and group by but not yet.
- The TOTAL column will be counted based on the SIZE and NAME columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to format your date accordingly using `DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m")` to get the format `2021-03`. Then you can use `GROUP BY` along with `COUNT(*)`.

```
SELECT
    name,
    size,
    DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m") as month,
    COUNT(*) as Total
FROM test
GROUP BY
    name,
    size,
    DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m")
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC,
    name ASC;
```

| name | size | month | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2021-03 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 2021-03 | 2 |
| A | 2 | 2021-03 | 1 |
| C | 3 | 2021-03 | 1 |

Working example at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7edM78Qhp8wLZ1JJZoE3bH/1

It's not clear what order you want the results returned in, so you can change the `ORDER BY` clause to customize it how you want.

Answer (score 0):

select Name,Size,Cast(date as date) as Date,count(1) from tablename
group by Name,Size,Cast(date as date)

Comment: try with your command SQl , but it show table like this : https://prnt.sc/10oszkd